# Maximum size of the liststatus in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-flink

I am wondering that the maximum size of the `liststatus` in the `flink-connector-file` code when calling the code below?

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus[] hadoopFiles = this.fs.listStatus(toHadoopPath(f));
```

If the target path have the billions of billions of files, then when I call the `liststatus` as below, then the exception is thrown?

Then, how to prevent them in the app's code?

Thanks,